# proper way of doing auto complete dropdown in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

hello friends I am new in angular 2 I find the way to auto complete dropdown I tried the ng2-select but it did not work for me. is there is another npm that work with angular 2. as the functionality is we also set the selected value for the dropdown as well? if you know any npm that provide autocomplete as well as set the initial value as well then suggest me thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `ngui-angular2-auto-complete` npm. It's working in my project. You can use. here the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngui-angular2-auto-complete)

Answer (score 1):

You can check out Material 2: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview